# Were primers for pistols in short supply?

Tags: technology

I am talking about pre-cartridge pistols which used primers. Gunpowder could be made from fairly available raw materials but primers not only required I think harder-to-come-by elements like mercury but also they were not easy to make from scratch. Were primers necessary for pistols or would pistols that used primers be somewhat functional without them? I can recall no movie and few books in which primers play much of a part -- where people discuss having powder but no primers for example. I would assume that people brought a lot of primers, which were small and relatively light weight, with them if they necessary.

The timeframe would be mid 19th century -- before cartridges but after flintlock. But the central question is, whenever percussion caps were used, how significant were shortages of those to, for example, armies or individual gun users?

Would even a relatively settled area like Texas in 1850 (in contrast to California at that time) have had a single factory manufacturing primers or did every single one come from the eastern United States?

The book Blood Meridian has a memorable chapter involving the gang of scalp hunters running out of gunpowder and making it from materials found in nature. Primers are mentioned elsewhere in the book, implying that their weapons used them, so I assume running out of powder meant they had also used many primers.

As I understand primers, they were fairly precisely-made items, having to fit weapons. They also contained fulminate of mercury which is not a substance easy to make, even if you have mercury, it is doubtful that even an expert could make it in primitive conditions.

I conclude that anyone traveling to the frontier regions of the the U.S. must have brought a huge number of primers with them. Lead bullets could be recast from recovered rounds or even from lead ore, I guess. Gunpowder was probably something entrepreneurs made in almost every town -- perhaps some of them made primers but as I mentioned, I never saw this discussed.

I could summarize the question: Where were primers obtained from in the mid 19th century?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  [history of primers](https://www.bevfitchett.us/ballistics/priming-compounds-and-primers-introduction.html)  I remember reading that primers would be in short supply in post apocalyptic scenarios because they are difficult to make; just can't remember where I read it.  As I understand, you can homebrew _bad_ primers, but not smokeless

Comment: For something like the Brown Bess, percussion caps would be roughly one percent of the weight of the total ball, powder, wadding, and cap. An individual who purchases gunpowder and lead could easily get a handful of caps, **if** they were in stock at the store. A shortage would be a supply chain issue, not a transportation capacity issue.

Comment: @o.m.: That supply chain issue is central to what I am thinking of. If people were in the 1850s U.S. west (as in Blood Meridian) far from factories, I am assuming once they were out of primers, they were out of luck. They could (as in Blood Meridian) make powder. So I am guessing people plan to travel to the frontier bought plenty of primers with them. Would there have even been a single factory in Texas or California in 1850 making primers? Or is it not as technically hard as I imagine?

Comment: Might want to update title to match new question summary -